# Symlink not working - Laravel 9 - Stored image not Showing from assets() function

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, storage, symlink

My Storage folder inside `**home/abc/abc**` but public files are inside home/abc/public_html and i have also created symlink inside public_html but symlink not working in laravel 9

```
My Storage folder inside `**home/abc/abc**` but public files are inside home/abc/public_html and i have also created symlink inside public_html but symlink not working in laravel 9
i have also command php artisan php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, what does the browser say when you manually try to insert the file url in the address bar? Does it say "file not found" or "forbidden" error?

Comment: it shows 404 not found error

Comment: have you checked you path ?

Comment: yes bro i ahve checked each and every thing like path, symlink etc\

Comment: Do you have two servers with load balancer or it's just one ? If they are two servers with load balancer this might be the issue. The request might go to the second one where the file is missing. They need to share common folder for both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Brother i have one server